# Respond with json in CakePHP controller

Tags: cakephp, response

My code looks something like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->Comment->Save();
    $this->set('comment', $this->Comment->read());
    $this->set('_serialize', array('comment');
}
```

Instead of responding with Ajax, I get an error that a view is missing. Is there something else that's needed to respond with json? I thought this was handled "automagically" with the response helper.

Answer (score 1):

```
By enabling RequestHandlerComponent in your application, and enabling support for the xml 
and or json extensions, you can automatically leverage the new view classes.
```

So you still need to enable a few things:

Add

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

and in routes.php

```
Router::parseExtensions(array('json'));
```

You may have to have your url look like controller/action.json for the automagic to work. You could just add $this->viewClass = 'Json' in the controller, though (not 100% sure on this).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding $this->viewClass = 'Json' worked, but the other way didn't.

Comment: Router::parseExtensions(array('json')) should be Router::parseExtensions('json'); the method uses variable arguments

Comment: @james is correct. I tried to edit the question but my edits got rejected. :-(